# In place extract tar archive

Tags: linux, archiving, extract, tar

I have a little dilemma here...

I needed to move about 70 GB worth of files from one of my servers to the other, so I decided that tarring them up and sending the archive would be the fastest way.

However, the receiving server only has 5 GB of space left after receiving the tar archive.

Is there some way I can extract the tar 'in-place'? I don't need to keep the archive after it has been extracted, so I was wondering if it is possible to do this.

**Edit:** It should be noted that the archive has already been sent, and I'd like to avoid resending via a different method.

Comment: The easiest solution would be to temporarily add another disk or USB pendrive to the server, move the archive to the new disk and extract it from there. This will probably be faster than extracting and deleting many files in a loop.

Answer (score 11):

```
% tar czf - stuff_to_backup | ssh backupmachine tar xvzf -
```

this translates to:

- tar and compress 'stuff_to_backup' to stdout
- login to 'backupmachine' via ssh
- run 'tar' on the 'backupmachine' and untar the stuff coming in from stdin

i personally would use 'rsync over ssh' to transfer the stuff because you can continue transfering stuff if the connection breaks:

```
% rsync -ar --progress -e 'ssh' 'stuff_to_backup' user@backupmachine:/backup/
```

which will transfer everything from 'stuff_to_backup' to the 'backup' folder on the 'backupmachine'. if the connection breaks, just repeat the command. if some files in 'stuff_to_backup' change, repeat the stuff, only the difference will be transfered.

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: yes, you left the important part out in the first place. :)

Answer (score 6):

If the other machine has ssh, I would recommend you rsync as another alternative that does not use a tar file:

```
rsync -avPz /some/dir/ user@machine:/some/other/dir/
```

And be careful with the leading `/`

**Edit update**

Well, I see how this is now a great pickle if you are not able to delete it and recommence with rsync. I would probably try a selective extract and delete from the tar.

selective extract:

```
$ tar xvf googlecl-0.9.7.tar googlecl-0.9.7/README.txt
googlecl-0.9.7/README.txt
```

selective delete:

```
$ tar --delete --file=googlecl-0.9.7.tar googlecl-0.9.7/README.txt
```

However, it seems that you will spend a lot of time coding a script for this...

Comment: See my edited question

Comment: See my edited answer... good luck :-/

Comment: Thanks for the edit. The files are actually named with numbers, so a quick for loop in bash might just do the trick.

Comment: @Charlie Somerville: you might have to start with the files stored at the end of the tar, otherwise you might end with tar creating a new archive ... so, delete the files from the end of the tar first.

Answer (score 5):

Basically, what you need is the possibility to pipe the file into tar, and "lop" the front as you go.

On StackOverflow, somebody asked how to [truncate a file at front](https://stackoverflow.com/q/706167/324969), but it seems it isn't possible. You could still fill the begining of the file with zeroes in a special way so the file becomes a [sparse file](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_file), but I don't know how to do this. We can truncate the end of the file, though. But tar needs to read the archive forwards, not backwards.

**Solution 1**

A level of indirection solves every problem. First reverse the file in-place, then read it backwards (which will result in reading the original file forwards) and truncate the end of the reversed file as you go.

You'll need to write a program (c, python, whatever) to exchange the begining and the end of the file, chunk by chunk, and then pipe these chunks to tar while truncating the file a chunk at a time. This is the basis for solution 2 which is maybe simpler to implement.

**Solution 2**

Another method is to [split the file in small chunks in-place](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10489987/324969), then delete those chunks as we extract them. The code below has a chunk size of one megabyte, adjust depending on your needs. Bigger is faster but will take more intermediate space when splitting and during extraction.

*Split the file archive.tar :*

```
archive="archive.tar"
chunkprefix="chunk_"
# 1-Mb chunks :
chunksize=1048576

totalsize=$(wc -c "$archive" | cut -d ' ' -f 1)
currentchunk=$(((totalsize-1)/chunksize))
while [ $currentchunk -ge 0 ]; do
    # Print current chunk number, so we know it is still running.
    echo -n "$currentchunk "
    offset=$((currentchunk*chunksize))
    # Copy end of $archive to new file
    tail -c +$((offset+1)) "$archive" > "$chunkprefix$currentchunk"
    # Chop end of $archive
    truncate -s $offset "$archive"
    currentchunk=$((currentchunk-1))
done
```

*Pipe those files into tar (note we need the chunkprefix variable in the second terminal) :*

```
mkfifo fifo
# In one terminal :
(while true; do cat fifo; done) | tar -xf -
# In another terminal :
chunkprefix="chunk_"
currentchunk=0
while [ -e "$chunkprefix$currentchunk" ]; do
    cat "$chunkprefix$currentchunk" && rm -f "$chunkprefix$currentchunk"
    currentchunk=$((currentchunk+1))
done > fifo
# When second terminal has finished :
# flush caches to disk :
sync
# wait 5 minutes so we're sure tar has consumed everything from the fifo.
sleep 300
rm fifo
# And kill (ctrl-C) the tar command in the other terminal.
```

Since we use a named pipe (`mkfifo fifo`), you don't have to pipe all chunks at once. This can be useful if you're really tight on space. You can follow the following steps :

- Move, say the last 10Gb chunks to another disk,
- Start the extraction with the chunks you still have,
- When the `while [ -e … ]; do cat "$chunk…; done` loop has finished (second terminal) :
- **do NOT stop the `tar` command, do NOT remove the fifo** (first terminal), but you can run `sync`, just in case,
- Move some extracted files which you know are complete (tar isn't stalled waiting for data to finish extracting these files) to another disk,
- Move the remaining chunks back,
- Resume extraction by running the `while [ -e … ]; do cat "$chunk…; done` lines again.

Of course this is all *haute voltige*, you'll want to check everything is ok on a dummy archive first, because **if you make a mistake then goodbye data**.

You'll never know if the first terminal (`tar`) has actually finished processing the contents of the fifo, so if you prefer you can run this instead, but you won't have the possibility to seamlessly exchange chunks with another disk :

```
chunkprefix="chunk_"
currentchunk=0
while [ -e "$chunkprefix$currentchunk" ]; do
    cat "$chunkprefix$currentchunk" && rm -f "$chunkprefix$currentchunk"
    currentchunk=$((currentchunk+1))
done | tar -xf -
```

**Disclaimer**

Note that for all this to work, your shell, tail and truncate must handle 64-bit integers correctly (you don't need a 64-bit computer nor operating system for that). Mine does, but if you run the above script on a system without these requirements, **you'll loose all the data in archive.tar**.

**And in any case something other than that goes wrong, you'll loose all the data in archive.tar anyway, so make sure you have a backup of your data.**

Answer (score 0):

If you have object files to be moved across, try stripping them. This will save a considerable amount of space.

```
$ strip `find . -name "*.bin"`
```

Answer (score 0):

I transferred a 3TB tar file to a 4TB remote drive which took 24 hours, so I too wasn't keen on repeating the process. This is the script I ended up using. It creates a list of files in tar and extracts them in reverse order.

The hope is that tar will just 'kind-of' truncate the tar file instead of overwriting it on each file removal. Unfortunately, this does not seem to be the case and the extract/delete loop is terribly slow.

Someone might still find this script useful with small-ish files (few GBs).

```bsh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e
set -u

if [ "$#" -ne 1 ]; then
  echo "Usage $0 <path-to.tar>"
  exit 1
fi

TAR_FILE_PATH="$1"
TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH=$( mktemp )

echo "Using temporary file: '$TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH'"

if [ ! -f "$TAR_FILE_PATH" ]; then
  echo "File doesn't exist '$TAR_FILE_PATH'"
  exit 1
fi

# Create list of files in the tar file. Reverse the line order
tar --list -f "$TAR_FILE_PATH" | tac > "$TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH"

# Go over each file in "$TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH" and first extract it, then delete it from the archive
while IFS= read -r THE_FILE; do
  echo "Extracting '$THE_FILE'"
  tar --extract -f "$TAR_FILE_PATH" "$THE_FILE"
  tar --delete -f "$TAR_FILE_PATH" "$THE_FILE"
done < "$TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH"

rm "$TAR_FILE_CONTENTS_PATH"
```

Comment: Processing a big `tar` file this way is slow because it doesn't contain a directory of all files, so all file headers in the whole file must be read sequentially to find the last file in the archive for extracting or deleting it in every loop cycle. Even the fact that it's the last file in the archive can be detected only from the data that follows the file. Maybe the speed can be improved a bit by extracting and deleting files in bigger chunks, e.g. 10 files or 100 files each.