# simple way to extract tar.gz in-place with no hard-drive overhead

Tags: linux, hard-drive, unix, tar, gzip

I'm working with a tar.gz file (196 GB). This file needs to be extracted (240 GB) in place, and I would like the total disk usage not to go over 240 GB during the process (or close to it as possible). Is there any way this can be done?

I am familiar with `--remove-files`. I don't think this will limit the total disk requirements. I also understand that gunzip automatically extracts and removes the source file (but the .tar would still need to be extracted). Does the `gunzip <file>` command require more disk space than the extracted tar?

To summarize:

- Question 1: What is the simplest way to extract a .tar.gz in-place with minimal hard storage overhead
- Question 2: Can I set up the sub-operations `gunzip <file>` and `tar --remove-files` to do the above?

My backup solution is to store chunked data and extract iteratively, but I would rather have a simple non-recursive solution.

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/421756/432690). Wherever there's `… | tar -xf -` you need `… | gzip -cd | tar -xf -`. I haven't tested this in detail but the whole approach seems quite sane.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a high speed Internet (Fast enough to upload the archive file)

OR

Link of the archive file from where you downloaded

OR

Link to google drive for archive

> Use online Archive extractor...
>
> 1) upload or link the archive file
>
> 2) download the extracted contents